# Hot fix entre dos git remotos

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Tengo dos repositorios git remotos, uno es de test y el otro es de produccion

```
git remote -v
produccion      https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1.git (fetch)
produccion      https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1.git (push)
test    https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1_test.git (fetch)
test    https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1_test.git (push)
```

se trabaja en el de test, se hace el

```
git push test master
```

testing hace el pull, prueba el cambio y si está ok se pasa a produccion

```
git push produccion master
```

el problema está cuando test tiene muchas funcionalidades a testear pero hay que hacer un hot fix de un cambio sin pasar todos los commits


ejemplo :

```
repositorio de test : 
test commit 6 - hotfix (se arreglo algo) 
test commit 5
test commit 4
test commit 3 - hasta acá esta igual que produccion
test commit 2
test commit 1
```

```
repositorio de produccion: 
produccion commit 3
produccion commit 2
produccion commit 1
```

quiero subir al repositorio de produccion el commit 6 sin subir el commit 4 ni el 5

es posible hacer el push de un solo commit sin que pase los anteriores?

gracias

Answer (score 1):

Parece que es una ocasión perfecta para `git cherry-pick`.

Cherry-pick (literalmente, *elegir cerezas*; realmente, *manipular*) consiste en coger un commit de una rama y ponerlo en otra.

Por tanto, lo ideal en este caso sería:

1. Saliendo de master (lo que está en producción) crea un hotfix del tipo hotfix-esto_no_funciona.
2. Publica estos cambios.
3. Obtén el SHA de los commits con los cambios, digamos XXX.
4. Desde la rama donde quieres introducir estos cambios, ejecuta:

   ```
   git cherry-pick <hash-del-commit>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

La solución depende de si acaso en `test commit 4` y `test commit 5` modificaste el o los mismos archivos que se modifican en `test commit 6: hotfix`

En el caso optimista, donde tu hotfix no toca lo que está contenido en los commits 4 y 5, probablemente te sirva hacer lo que dice [@fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui).

Supongamos que tu historial de commits es como sigue

```
946db3c1e commit 1
f74e10d42 commit 2
24177c9fe commit 3 # igual a producción
6409d80f1 commit 4
7294e5d11 commit 5
ce322c2b2 commit 6 # aplica hotfix
```

Entonces podrías hacer

```
git checkout -b hotfix  // creas una nueva rama llamada "hotfix" desde master
git reset --hard 24177c9fe // vuelves al último ancestro común con producción
git cherry-pick ce322c2b2 // aplicas el commit 6 encima del 3
git push production hotfix:master // pusheas el hotfix hacia producción
```

El problema, incluso si estamos en el camino feliz y el commit 6 no toca las modificaciones de los commits 4 y 5, el `cherry-pick` que acabas de hacer aplica los mismos cambios del commit 6 pero **lleva un hash distinto**.

En producción podría quedar, por ejemplo:

```
946db3c1e commit 1
f74e10d42 commit 2
24177c9fe commit 3 # igual a producción
eabcfebdb commit 6 # aplica hotfix
```

El hash del commit 6 en producción no es igual al hash del commit 6 en master.

Mi sugerencia sería ocupar [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Vas a ver una lista con los últimos 3 commits

```
pick 6409d80f1 commit 4
pick 7294e5d11 commit 5
pick ce322c2b2 commit 6 # aplica hotfix
```

Puedes reordenarlos y dejar en cambio:

```
pick ce322c2b2 commit 6 # aplica hotfix
pick 6409d80f1 commit 4
pick 7294e5d11 commit 5
```

Al guardar, se va a reescribir la historia de los que reordenaste, quedando por ejemplo

```
pick e7985db68 commit 6 # aplica hotfix
pick 454f2a7b7 commit 4
pick f6349516a commit 5
```

Esto significa que tu rama local habrá divergido de test/master y tendrás que hacer

```
git push test master -f
```

para volver a quedar a la par con el repo de test.

Ahora te devuelves al commit del hotfix y haces el push a producción (suponiendo que te aprobaron el hotfix)

```
git reset --hard e7985db68 // el nuevo hash de commit 6
git push production master
```

hecho esto, puedes volver a ponerte en el commit más reciente, que ahora es el llamado "commit 5"

```
git reset --hard f6349516a // el nuevo hash del commit 5
```

Ahora bien, **si en los commits 4 y 5 modificaste los mismos archivos que en el commit 6**, al aplicar el `rebase` te va a alegar por conflictos (si añades una línea en el commit 4 y la modificas en el 6, no hace sentido modificarla antes de añadirla...). Tendrás que resolver esos eventuales conflictos para terminar el rebase, pero lo importante es que al terminar ese paso ya estarás en condiciones de volver al commit 6, pushear a producción, y luego volver al commit 5 que pasó a ser el más reciente.

#### Nota al márgen

Me parece que el flujo de trabajo que han implementado es confuso. Cuando reciben el visto bueno para "pasar a producción", en vez de hacerlo mediante un Pull Request, que es la manera específicamente diseñada para manejar esta operación, hacen un push al remoto de producción, con lo cual generan un merge implícito que no deja historia de los cambios, no está sujeto a checks de integración continua, cobertura de tests, pruebas unitarias, etc. ni tampoco puede recibir comentarios o correcciones, sino que el feedback supongo que te llega de manera verbal, por chat o por correo.

Sería mucho más sencillo si usaran el mismo repo y trabajaran en distintas branches. Github permite determinar que ciertas ramas estén protegidas y sólo un admin pueda mergear un determinado pull request hacia esas ramas, mientras que el resto de los desarrolladores trabaja en branches temporales para abordar features o hotfixes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]